# Regex: getting html attributes

Tags: regex

I try to get all html attributes but getting only one encapsilating others
my pattern is:

```
(\S+)=((".*")|('.*')|(\S*(?=(\s+))))
```

Content is:

> ```
> <a href="html.aspx" target="_blank" />
> ```

And only one matche returns:

- href="html.aspx" target="_blank"

But I want it to be:

- href="html.aspx"
- target="_blank"

Any helps would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're using greedy matching (the default) with `.*"` which will keep going until it finds the *last* `"`. Try this regex:

```
(\S+)=((".*?")|('.*?')|(\S*(?=(\s+))))
```

The `.*?"` tells the regex to search until the *first* `"`, not the last one.